# Calculating regression line from given quantile of values depending on category

Tags: r, ggplot2, filtering, subset, quantile

I have a quite huge dataframe (nearly 100,000 observations with about 40 variables) from which I want ggplot to draw scatterplots with lm- or loess-lines. But the lines should be calculated only based on a certain quantile of variable-values of each observation date. And I would like to do the filtering or subsetting directly in ggplot without creating a new data object or subdataframe in advance.

As my 'real' dataframe would be too large I created fictive example with a dataframe of 144 observations named *df_Bandvals* (Code at the end of the post). 
 Here following structure, the first 25 lines and a scatterplot with a loess-line based on ALL observations

```
> str(df_Bandvals)
'data.frame':   144 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ obsdate      : int  190101 190101 190101 190101 190101 190101 190101 190101 190101 190101 ...
 $ transsect    : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ PointNr      : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ depth        : num  31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
 $ Band12plusmin: num  169 241 229 159 221 196 188 216 233 149 ...

> df_Bandvals
    obsdate transsect PointNr depth Band12plusmin
1    190101         A       1    31           169
2    190101         A       2    31           241
3    190101         A       3    31           229
4    190101         A       4    31           159
5    190101         A       5    31           221
6    190101         A       6    31           196
7    190101         B       1    31           188
8    190101         B       2    31           216
9    190101         B       3    31           233
10   190101         B       4    31           149
11   190101         B       5    31           169
12   190101         B       6    31           181
13   190102         A       1     3           356
14   190102         A       2     3           368
15   190102         A       3     3           293
16   190102         A       4     3           261
17   190102         A       5     3           313
18   190102         A       6     3           374
19   190102         B       1     3           327
20   190102         B       2     3           409
21   190102         B       3     3           369
22   190102         B       4     3           334
23   190102         B       5     3           376
24   190102         B       6     3           318
25   190103         A       1    25           183
```

[image]

The plot shows *depth* vs. *Band12plusmin* with an according loess-line. Point colors are assigned to the respective observation date (*obsdate*). Each observation date includes 12 observations. 
Now, my basic question was: How to get a loess line based only on the lower 50%-quantile *Band12plusmin*-values of each observation date? Or in other words with referring to the plot: ggplot should only use the 6 lower points of each color for calculating the line.

And as mentioned before I would like to do the filtering or subsetting directly in ggplot without creating a new data object or subdataframe in advance.

I tried around with subsetting, but my problem in this case is that I cannot just specify a universal *Band12plusmin*-threshold as, of course, the 50%-treshold individually differs for each *obsdate*-group.  I am quite new to R and ggplot, so, for now I failed to find a solution for that say class-individual-derived-threshold-conditionned filtering.
May anybody help here?

Here the code of the dataframe and plot

```
obsdate<-rep(c(190101:190112),each=12, mode=factor)
transsect<-rep(rep(c("A","B"), each=6), 12)
PointNr<-rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), times=24)
depth<-rep(c(31,3,25,-9,13,18,7,-10,3,-4,11,21),each=12)
Band12<-rep(c(199,349,225,844,257,231,301,875,378,521,210,246), each=12)
set.seed(13423)
plusminRandom<-round(rnorm(144, mean=0, sd=33))
plusminRandom
Band12plusmin<-Band12+plusminRandom
df_Bandvals<-data.frame(obsdate, transsect, PointNr, depth, Band12plusmin)
str(df_Bandvals)
head(df_Bandvals, 20)

library (ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df_Bandvals, aes(x=depth, y=Band12plusmin))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-15, 35))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(120, 960))+
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(obsdate)), size=1.5)+
  geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

Comment: The three backticks to end a code block need to be on their own line - I've edited accordingly so your image shows up.

Comment: RE: *"I would like to do the filtering or subsetting directly in ggplot without creating a new data object or subdataframe in advance"* - I'm curious **why** you have this requirement. It would be trivial to solve this problem with a couple lines of `dplyr`  in advance. Would it be acceptable if the `dplyr` code is nested within the `ggplot` call? If not, I think this problem becomes much harder, as you're relying on a graphics package to do data manipulation without any help from data manipulation packages.

Comment: Thanks for your support with the image. My intention with 'not creating new objects' was to get some quick plots for preview purposes without coding 'too much' and without filling up my environment with lots of objects that I'll not keep in the end. However, I am interested also in alternatives. So, if you would like to show me how to proceed with dplyr you are welcome. Thanks anyway!

Comment: My idea was just as Harrison showed in the accepted answer - I was worried that a solution like that would not meet your criteria because it's not ggplot itself doing the data work. I see you've accepted the answer, so my worry was unfounded.

Comment: I would consider me more or less an R-beginner not being aware of all the packages and their nesting options.
So, if I understood you right, Harrison's solution was using dplyr-code yet? In that sense of 'nested dplyr-ggplot code' you were speaking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `data` argument within `geom_smooth()`

```
ggplot(data = df_Bandvals, aes(x = depth, y = Band12plusmin)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-15, 35)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(120, 960)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(obsdate)), size = 1.5) +
  geom_smooth(
    data = df_Bandvals %>% 
      group_by(obsdate) %>%
      filter(Band12plusmin < median(Band12plusmin)), 
    method = "loess"
  )
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks